# Can I use the built in SD card copier to copy the SD card I am running the OS from?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

Can I use the built in SD card copier to copy the SD card I am running the OS from?

Hello,

Raspbian comes with a built in SD card copier application. Can I use it to make a copy of the 64 GB SD card that I am actually running Rasbian on? Or will running the OS and copying it simultaneously lead to copying errors?

Vesa

Raspberry Pi 3 B

Comment: Why not try it?

Answer (score 1):

The SD card copier was designed for running Raspbian systems. In fact, it couldn't work otherwise since it copies files from the ext4 rootfs instead of raw sectors.

Linux does not lock files against multiple concurrent reads by default, so this is not a problem.